# Reload ReactJS page in development returns me blank

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

whenever I click the 'reload' button on my browser during my ReactJS development, my page turns up blank and I have to go back to the base URL and start all over. May I know what I can do to keep some sort of 'history'?

I am using React-Router v4

webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
        disableDotRule: true,
        index: 'build/index.html
    }
}
```

My devServer has no output properties, only in the prodConfig:

```
output: {
    path: path.join(_dirname, '/build'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/work/'
}
```

Directory:

```
/
- src
    - index.html
- webconfig.js
```

Cheers.

*Edit: added webpack code snippet

Comment: You need to make sure that you serve `index.html` for all of your routes so that React Router can take care of the routing in the browser.

Comment: This is probably a .htaccess issue

Comment: Are you using an express server? or only React and react-router? and, are you using webpack?

Comment: @Tholle How do i "make" sure i server index.html for all routes?

Comment: @c-chavez I am using a webpack

Comment: @AKJ can you please add all your webpack config?

Comment: @AKJ I'm interested in the `output` properties

Comment: @AKJ and where is your index.html located exactly within the directory tree?

Comment: @c-chavez where is output?

Comment: @AKJ in your `webpack.config.js`, there should be an output... but it's easier if you post your complete `webpack.config.js` file.

Comment: @c-chavez Codes is in company env and I cannot post codes here.

Comment: @AKJ this makes it tough, but just make sure that `devServer: { historyApiFallback: { index: ` is pointing to the correct path for your index.html. Try with `index: 'src/index.html` or `index: '/src/index.html`. There is also a `publicPath` property inside `devServer`, set that one to `publicPath: '/'` and see if that works.

Comment: @c-chavez What is the diff between the index pointing to the build/index.html and the src/index.html? And also, is it alright if my devServer has no output? Because I have no publichPath in devServer

Comment: @AKJ `build/index.html` is just an example where index.html is inside a folder called `build`. You have to adjust it so that it points out to the correct folder structure. You added a structure where index.html seems to be inside a folder called src, that's why I suggested `src/index.html`. If `devServer` is alright, but it would be extremely helpful to see the complete webpack config. Webpack is tricky, but just play with what I wrote in the answer and these examples and you should be set to go.

Comment: Thanks so much @c-chavez do i have to wrap the publicPath with an output and park one under the devServer as well?

Comment: @AKJ no you don't have to, but again, webpack is tricky. In my opinion try following [the official docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) first. Also, have a look at [this article](https://hackernoon.com/a-tale-of-webpack-4-and-how-to-finally-configure-it-in-the-right-way-4e94c8e7e5c1) and [this as well](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-conquer-webpack-4-and-build-a-sweet-react-app-236d721e6745) to help you with webpack config.

Comment: Alright, thanks mate, will do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using webpack, you can either set the `historyApiFallback` property of `devServer` like this:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
},
```

or like this (assuming index.html is located in your build directory):

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback:{
        index:'build/index.html'
    },
},
```

Change 'build/index.html' to point to the correct index.html path.

**Alternatively**, set it directly when you run the script in your `package.json`, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start" : "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback"
},
```

Have a look at the official docs of webpack [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/cli/history-api-fallback) and [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback).

Comment: I added the historyApiFallback into the devServer, but it is still not working. Does it have something to do with the Routes and History objects? I tried it out, but couldnt get it to work